# How to easily put two pages onto one page (2up on one page)?

Tags: tables, floats, minipage, multicolumn, page

**Update**

Just to give a bit background information, full file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KFXlfZfSpQUmrZHq4t4zocYZrL_9Uwoy). Or if you are a teacher, use [this link](https://www.tes.com/teaching-resource/numeracy-mental-arithmetic-sample-packs-11950349). I am trying to make a `table of content` link page in the `bigger` document. At the moment, it's over two pages. I want to use the easiest way to make them onto a single page.

Best attempt got this:
[image]
Seem to be very difficult to scale two pages onto one AND preserves the hyperref links...

**OP**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8]{ctexrep}
% 
\CTEXoptions[today=old]
%% packages
\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate,amsfonts}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} % \caption*
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=.3cm,left=1cm,right=1.5cm,marginparsep=0.1cm,marginparwidth=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\maxval}{\texttt{maxval}}
\newcommand{\mycode}[1]{\hyperref[code:#1]{#1}}
\newcommand{\mynote}[3]{\hyperref[code:#1]{#1} & {\heiti #2} & #3 \\}

%% DOC content

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\heiti

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}\label{nav}
    \caption*{ \large \heiti \nameref{code:A}}
    \begin{tabular}{c l l l}
    \toprule
        A0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \color{red}{ 1-$n$以内加减法(算式+填空) } } \\
        \mynote{A1}{不进位加法}{addition that does not carry over}
        \mynote{A2}{不退位减法}{subtraction that does not borrow}
        \mynote{A3}{进位加法}{addition that carries over}
        \mynote{A4}{退位减法}{subtraction that borrows}
        \mynote{A5}{不进退位组合}{mixture of \mycode{A1} and \mycode{A2} }
        \mynote{A6}{进退位组合}{mixture of \mycode{A3} and \mycode{A4}}
        \mynote{A7}{进位加不退位减}{mixture of \mycode{A3} and \mycode{A2}}
        \mynote{A8}{任意混合}{any mixture of the above}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
%%

\begin{table}
    \caption*{ \large \heiti \nameref{code:B}}
    \begin{tabular}{c l l l}
    \toprule
        B0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \color{red}{ 2.0-加减乘除混合(算式+填空) } } \\
        \mynote{B1}{乘法}    {Multiplication}
        \mynote{B2}{除法}    {Division}
        \mynote{B3}{乘除混合}{Multiplication and Division}
        \mynote{B4}{乘混加减}{Multiplication with Addition and Subtraction}
        \mynote{B5}{除混加减}{Division with Addition and Subtraction}
        \mynote{B6a}{加减乘除 (算式)}{Addition or Subtraction or Multiplication or Division (sums)}
        \mynote{B6b}{加减乘除 (填空)}{Addition or Subtraction or Multiplication or Division (fill in the blanks)}
        \mynote{B7}{加减混合}{Addition and Subtraction}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%
\begin{table}
    \caption*{ \large \heiti \nameref{code:C}}
    \begin{tabular}{c l l l}
    \toprule
        C0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \color{red}{ 2.1 / 2.3 / 3.1 } } \\
        \mynote{C1} {九九乘法表 (算式)}{times table up to  9 (sums)}
        \mynote{C2} {英文乘法表 (算式)}{times table up to 12 (sums)}
        \mynote{C3} {九九乘法表 (填空)}{times table up to  9 (fill in the blanks)}
        \mynote{C4} {英文乘法表 (填空)}{times table up to 12 (fill in the blanks)}
        \mynote{C5} {九九乘法表 (中文口诀)}{times table (Chinese version)}
        \mynote{C6} {余数练习}{division with remainder (up to  9 times table)}
        \mynote{C7} {余数练习}{division with remainder (up to 12 times table)}
        \mynote{C8} {连乘}{multiplication after multiplication (\maxval $\times$ \maxval $\times$ \maxval )}
        \mynote{C9} {连除}{division after division (\maxval $\div$ \maxval $\div$ \maxval )}
        \mynote{C10}{乘 连(and) 除}{one multiplication and one division}
        \mynote{C11}{连乘 或(or) 连除}{(multiplication after multiplication) OR (division after division)}
        \mynote{C12}{乘除 混合(mixture)题}{any mixture of multiplication and division}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%



\begin{table}
    \caption*{ \large \heiti \nameref{code:D}}
    \begin{tabular}{c l l l}
    \toprule
        D0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \color{red}{ 2.4-混合运算1-连加连减 } } \\
        \mynote{D1}{连加-后凑整    }{ Addition only, number bounds in last two terms }
        \mynote{D2}{连加减-后减凑整}{ Addition then subtraction, number bounds in last two terms }
        \mynote{D3}{连加-随机凑整  }{ Addition only, random number bounds}
        \mynote{D4}{连加减-随机凑整}{ Addition then subtraction, random number bounds}
        \mynote{D5}{后凑整组合     }{ Grouping the last two terms (number bounds)}
        \mynote{D6}{随机凑整组合   }{ Random number bounds}
        \mynote{D7}{随机连加       }{ Random addition only}
        \mynote{D8}{随机连减       }{ Random subtraction only}
        \mynote{D9}{随机连加减     }{ Random addition and subtraction}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%
\begin{table}
    \caption*{ \large \heiti \nameref{code:E}}
    %
    \begin{tabular}{c l l l}
    \toprule
        E0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \color{red}{ 2.5-混合运算2-连加减带括号 } } \\
        \mynote{E1}{随机连加减       }{ Random addition and subtraction }
        \mynote{E2}{减连括号        }{ Subtraction with brackets }
        \mynote{E3}{连加减混合括号  }{ Random addition and subtraction with brackets }
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%

\begin{table}
    \caption*{ \large \heiti \nameref{code:F}}
    %
    \begin{tabular}{c l l l}
    \toprule
        F0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \color{red}{ 2.6-混合运算3-乘除连加减带括号 } } \\
        \mynote{F1} {乘法连加法 \, 乘除在前 \quad\, 无括号}{Multiplication then addition (no brackets)}
        \mynote{F2} {乘法连加法 \, 乘除在前 \quad\, 有括号}{Multiplication then addition (with brackets)}
        \mynote{F3} {乘法连加法 \, 加减在前 \quad\, 无括号}{Addition then multiplication (no brackets)}
        \mynote{F4} {乘法连加法 \, 加减在前 \quad\, 有括号}{Addition then multiplication (with brackets)}
        \mynote{F5} {乘法连减法 \, 加减在前 \quad\, 无括号}{Subtraction then multiplication (no brackets)}
        \mynote{F6} {乘法连减法 \, 加减在前 \,  随机括号}{Subtraction then multiplication (random brackets)}
        \mynote{F7} {乘法连加减 \, 加减在前 \quad\, 无括号}{Addition/Subtraction then multiplication}
                                                        & & (no brackets) \\
        \mynote{F8} {乘法连加减 \, 加减在前 \,  随机括号}{Addition/Subtraction then multiplication}
                                                        & & (random brackets) \\
        \mynote{F9} {乘法连加减 \, 随机顺序 \,  随机括号}{Addition/Subtraction and multiplication}
                                                        & & (random brackets, random order) \\
        \mynote{F10}{四则运算}{BIDMAS}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

This `MWE` complies fine. All I want to do is to put `these` two pages onto a single page.

This is the `view` from Adobe reader by `viewing two pages`:
[image]
[image]
How can I get this as single page straight away?

I have tried `multicolumn` and `minipage`, either works due to the `table` environment. For example, the error from using `minipage` is

> LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Any other options (without having to change to much)?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to produce a 2-up PDF? Or do you mean that you want your current PDF to display 2-up in Adobe reader, by default when you first open it?

Comment: If you want to produce a 2-up PDF, run `pdfnup` on your PDF file (uses `pdfpages` package internally). If you simply want to display 2-up in Adobe reader then `hyperref` can do this. Use `\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnRight]{hyperref}`

Comment: @DavidPurton I want these two pages to be 2-up, AND preserve the hyper links too. How do I do that internally? I have only tried it externally, which messes up the hyperref links.

Comment: What about using `a3paper`, `landscape`, `twocolumn`, and setting up everything using `geometry`?

Comment: @DavidPurton hmmm. I will have a go later. As the whole document has 65 pages, one column on A4, some. This might not be ideal? But as long as it works, I wouldn't bother too much ...

Comment: @DavidPurton I think A3 is `too` big for three tables on one side/column. Tried to force them using a `clearpage`. Difficult to scale them. Not easy to implement to the whole doc. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstand what you mean. But my suggestion is to use a3 as a kind of fake 2up. Use twocolumn mode to make it look like you have two a4 pages side by side. You could then scale at printing stage if you need to print. Doesn't matter how big the page is for screen. Add `twocolumn` to your document class and then load geometry like this: `\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=.3cm,left=1cm,right=1.5cm,marginparsep=0.1cm,marginparwidth=0.5cm,a3paper,landscape,columnsep=2.5cm]{geometry}
` Rest of your document can remain the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81871/discussion-between-chen-stats-yu-and-david-purton).